# Android Bluetooth Chat sample Fail while Transferring Large XML file

Tags: android, xml, bluetooth, interrupt

I am using Bluetooth chat sample in my application while transferring XML using Bluetooth chat sometimes it will be able to send half of the XML it is getting interrupt.And other device received only half of the XML,can anyone help me getting out of this
Thaking you in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

In BluetoothChatService.java's, ConnectedThread's run() method, change

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
```

to

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
```